# Подсветка тегов в Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Может кто вспомнит на вскидку, **как поменять цвет подсветки тегов**..
А то установил на новый комп eclipse а он вот так ярко подсвечивает теги.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел сам) Если кому понадобится:
Window -> Preferences

далее вводим "annotations" в поиске и выбираем "Matching Tags". Там настраиваем цвет.

[image]